# Encoding of username:password in Proxy-Authorize HTTP header

Tags: proxy, http, encoding

We use an explicit proxy to access the Internet.

This is what the HTTP header for "407 Proxy-Authentication required" looks like:

```
Proxy-Authenticate: BASIC realm="xxx"\r\n
Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n
Pragma: no-cache\r\n
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n
Proxy-Connection: close\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
Content-Length: 813\r\n
```

Now when transmitting the Proxy-Authorize header (the following step when the browser transmits credentials), behavior seems to be different between browsers (here password=passwörd):

Using FF or IE (here IE):

```
Credentials: user:passw\366rd   <----------- ISO-8859
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*\r\n
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr-LU;q=0.5,fr;q=0.3\r\n
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko\r\n
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
```

Using Chrome

```
Credentials: user:passw\303\266rd   <----------- UTF-8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36\r\n
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3\r\n
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\n
```

Using FF or IE the proxy complains that the encoding is not what it expects. This means that it expects UTF-8 since auth using Chrome is working.

---

I found this online:

> Previously, Firefox was using the ISO-8859-1 character encoding for
> the username and password in Basic HTTP authentication requests.
> Firefox 59 and later will use UTF-8 instead for the Authorization
> header to make sure non-ASCII characters like French accented letters
> are encoded properly.

However we are using FF 60.7.2ESR and it still seems to be sending ISO-8859 just like IE11 shown above.

---

There are several relevant RFCs: 7617, 7235, 7615.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617#section-2 states that

> For backwards compatibility reasons, this specification continues to
> leave the default encoding undefined, as long as it is compatible with
> US-ASCII (mapping any US-ASCII character to a single octet matching
> the US-ASCII character code).

Then, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617#section-2.1 states

> In challenges, servers can use the 'charset' authentication parameter
> to indicate the character encoding scheme they expect the user agent
> to use when generating "user-pass" (a sequence of octets). This
> information is purely advisory. The only allowed value is "UTF-8" ...

It gives an example: `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="foo", charset="UTF-8"`

And suggests the same applies to "Proxy-Authenticate: ".

**What does that mean for challenges when the password is *not* US-ASCII and *no* charset authentication parameter is sent?** It must not be undefined but it doesn't state what it should be then.

We could force the proxy to interpret everything as ISO-8859 but that would break everything where the client sends UTF-8.